# How can I switch the connection on my DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public partial class Accident_Reporting_Entities : DbContext
{
    public Accident_Reporting_Entities(string connectionString) : 
    base(getConnectionString(connectionString))
    {
    }

    public static string getConnectionString(string Facility) {
        switch (Facility) {
            case "Location1":
                return "Accident_Reporting_Entities";
            case "Location2":
                return "Accident_Reporting_2_Entities";
            case "Location3":
                return "Accident_Reporting_3_Entities";
            default:
                return "Accident_Reporting_Entities";
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I have made it so that `Accident_Reporting_Entities` connection can be changed.  I would like to know what the best practice would be in MVC 5 to set this variable.  I have thought about using a session variable, but I'm not sure this is the best way to go about setting this connection.

I'll give an example of how I would set this currently:

```
public class IncidentController : Controller
{
    private Accident_Reporting_Entities DB = new Accident_Reporting_Entities(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Facility"].ToString());

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateIncident(string Facility)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Facility"] = Facility;

        var incident = new AccidentSupervisorViewModel();
        incident.Departments = DB.Departments.ToList().Select(i => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.DepartmentName,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            }      
        );
        return View(incident);
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I run into the issue of the DB DbContext variable getting set after the view loads, so the DB connection is set to whatever it was previously set to before trying to use the `CreateIncident` action.  If I do a page refresh, it works fine.  Is there an alternative method other than a session variable that I am not thinking about, or a better way to set it to begin with?

Comment: search for something like `EF multi-tenancy` or `EF multi-tenant best practices`.

Comment: @SamAxe unfortunately I am limited to having multiple databases for this project, but that will be useful for future apps.

Comment: You should probably do something with a custom HttpHandler to customize the controller factory so you can set the connection string when the controller is created.

Comment: Whatever the best practice for storing the tenant key in a multi-tenant application, is probably a pretty good place to store the connectionstring key as well.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to not dispose the connection after using it (or even without using it). One way of preventing the issue you have is to implement the getter property which delays the initialization of the DB variable only when you need it